# maven Failed to collect dependencies for flapdoodle.embed.mongo

Tags: maven

I have an issue locally with maven range. Maven failed to collect dependencies for below dependency. But in deed, there is version for 3.4.6 which was downloaded already.
May u have any hints?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <version>[3.4.6,3.5.0)</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? JDK, plus your full pom file furthermore what does `Maven failed to collect dependencies for below` this mean? Log output? What do you mean by `collect`?

Comment: Please update your question with the error message. Run your maven command with `-X` for debug. Or try to [force updates](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-force-update)

Answer (score 1):

Check your internet connection also see if you need to configure proxy for your internet
I had similar issue and this fixed it.